# Running code after object graph is loaded

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to set some fields in an object graph that is loaded by Hibernate (joined tables).

```
public class A {
    long id;
    B b;
}

public class B {
    long id;
    String name;
}
```

The `onPostLoad()` method runs right after the object `A` is loaded, and `A.b` is still null. I need to run the code after the whole object graph is loaded, ex. to set a value into `A.b.name`. Is there any callback/event to use for this ?